# Can I use Aho-Corasick for epidemic spread simulation?

Tags: algorithms, simulated-data

I found that with this string-finding algorithm, this algo can determine if a string(person) holds something(if he has sick, already got vaccinated, and et cetera.).

I am trying to simulate an epidemic spread with simulation parameters and i can't find a simple mathematical method or algorithm that can help me to understand how i will do it with the simulation process.

ps: its my first time to ask a question here so dont judge if i cant follow the format..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The problem with the question is there isn't sufficient information to understand for example how you simulated the epidemic, spatial models, temporal, incorporating immunity? Is it the traditional R0 style deterministic models etc ... Thus it is not clear where Aho-Corasick would fit here. At a guess I can't see how it could drive a simulation.